# Wpf update UI without ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, arrays, observablecollection

I have a customer class which has a byte array property.
The application uses the byte array as a source for an image.
When I change this array, the UI doesn't update (since byte[] is not an ObservableCollection).

When can I do to force the UI to refresh?

EDIT : the image is saved as a byte array because that how it sits in the DB(varbinary(MAX)). I tried changing the type to IList but that popped errors in nhibernate : could not determine type for System..IList

Comment: You should probably look into INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your class implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

As soon as the Byte array changes, raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

For example:

```
class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private byte[] byteArray;

    public byte[] ByteArray
    {
        get
        {
            return byteArray;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != byteArray)
            {
                byteArray = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ByteArray");
            }
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: It does that a bit extra code but its reasonable and better then reloading the entire window. Thanks